# Basic objective-c question re comparisons in if statement

Tags: objective-c

I feel embarrassed asking this, but it seems like something I need to understand:

Why does this evaluate to true? (if I cast it to int it properly evaluates to false)

```
NSString *var1 = @"ABC";
NSString *var2 = @"ABCD";

if (([var1 length] - [var2 length]) > 2) NSLog(@"-1 > 2");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`length` is unsigned.

See [docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/length):

```
length
Returns the number of Unicode characters in the receiver.

- (NSUInteger)length

Return Value
The number of Unicode characters in the receiver.
```

Comment: Try:  if (((int)[var1 length] - (int)[var2 length]) > 2) NSLog(@"-1 > 2");

Comment: Or `if ([var1 length] > (2 + [var2 length]))` to avoid the subtraction. Look ma! I used algebra in the real world! (Of course, theoretically, you'd have to deal with overflow, but not realistically.)